# Enums of colors

Tags: .net, f#, colors, enums

My idea was to switch between some colors, so I don't have to use multiple pens but I can declare just one.

I'm not so sure to have understood exactly how enums work, please correct me:

```
type ColorType =
  | Red = Color.Red
  | Green = Color.Green
  | Blue = Color.Blue
```

and I wish to use it in:

```
let p = new Pen(ColorType.[index])
g.DrawRectangle(p, 0, 0, 10, 10)
```

where index is an int variable (0 to 2) I'll use to switch my colors. The problem is that I can't declare that enum, Color is not accepted. Possible solutions?

Comment: What exactly is `SpotColor`? Or should that be `ColorType`?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

To access the colors by index, you could put them in an array:

```
let colors =
  [|
    Color.Red
    Color.Green
    Color.Blue
  |]

let p = new Pen(colors.[index])
g.DrawRectangle(p, 0, 0, 10, 10)
```

Comment: +1 beat me to it :-) (I would normally delete the answer, but I wanted to add some more info.)

Answer (score 5):

You probably want to use an array or other collection to store your colors:

```
let colors = 
  [| Color.Red 
     Color.Green 
     Color.Blue |]

let p = new Pen(colors.[index]) 
g.DrawRectangle(p, 0, 0, 10, 10)
```

Enums are designed for a quite different purpose. They are useful if you want to enumerate a number of options and access them by name (instead of accessing them by i.e. index). You can use enums to represent states of some state machine, for example, or other options.

In your example, they would be useful if you wanted to associate different color with different type of graphical elements. Say you wanted to use one color for background and another for foreground - you could define enum or F# distriminated union to represent the two cases:

```
type ColorType = 
  | Foreground
  | Background
```

... and then you could define a collection that assigns the actual color to individual types:

```
let colors = 
  dict [ (ColorType.Foreground, Color.Red);
         (ColorType.Background, Color.Black) ]
```

Then you can use `colors.[ColorType.Foreground]` to get the color of a specified kind (which would be red, in this case). However, you cannot access cases of the enum (or F# discriminated union) by index.

This is quite basic aspect of F#, so you might want to check out the [F# WikiBook](http://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/F_Sharp_Programming), read some [introduction on MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh273069.aspx) or buy one of the F# books out there.